# Array object method wont work?

Tags: java

My method searchSong() doesnt work in my main.
Here is my object array from class Song

```
public class Library{
 Song[] thelist=new Song[10];
 int counter=0;
 private int i=0;

public void addSong(Song s){//adds Song method to array
    if(i<thelist.length){
    thelist[i]=s;
    i++;}
    else

  public Song searchSong(String title, String album, String author, String interpreter) {   
    for(int j=0;j<thelist.length;j++)
        if(thelist[j].title.equals(title) && thelist[j].album.equals(album) && thelist[j].author.equals(author) &&
             thelist[j].interpreter.equals(interpreter))

                return thelist[j];


            return null;}
```

in my main, I have to enter string title, album, author and interpreter to return the thelist[j].

here is my manin

```
 Library list=new Library();
 Song one=new Song();
 list.addSong(one);
 one.title="hello";
 one.album="world";
 one.interpreter="luar";
 one.author="me";
}
 list.searchSong(hello,world,luar,me);
```

the list.searchSong() method should return something but I keep getting this error

```
 TestLibrary.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    list.searchSong(hello,world,luar,me);
                    ^
  symbol:   variable hello
   location: class TestLibrary
    TestLibrary.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    list.searchSong(hello,world,luar,me);
```

Comment: Your search parameters take String parameters. If you are going to pass `String` literals you have to wrap them up in `""`. Other wise the compiler will think those are variable names and try to look for that variable.

Comment: Really, follow a tutorial on Java programming.

Comment: any links to great videos?

Comment: You can find lots of great videos [here](http://google.com).  I recommend bookmarking that site ;-)

Comment: Or here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put hello,world,luar,me in double quotes: "hello","world","luar","me"

Comment: TestLibrary.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
  list.searchSong("hello","world","luar","me");
      ^
  symbol:   method searchSong(String,String,String,String)
  location: variable list of type Librarythen I get this error

Comment: @luar - There's a long list of compiler errors in your immediate future.  We're not going to review each one with you as you learn to program.  Your best bet is to go do some basic tutorials so you understand the basics.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any *variables* named `hello`, `world`, `luar`, or `me`.  That's what Java is looking for.

I'm not sure of the structure of your `Song` object (or why you'd do this), but it seems that this is what you want.  I would presume that these fields are `String` literals, or you'd have compile failures much earlier:

```
list.searchSong(one.title, one.album, one.interpreter, one.author);
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the string literals.  However, that seems like a waste, since you already have that information living in one object already.

Oh - you also don't do anything with your return value.  You would want to capture that in an instance of a `Song`:

```
Song result = list.searchSong(one.title, one.album, one.interpreter, one.author);
```

Comment: Probably this is what luar meant to do...

Comment: +1 I'm unsure whether or not this question should even be answered, but at least you're not giving bad advice to pass string literals like everybody else.

Comment: the list will eventually hold 10 song objects so I need to search the array by title, album, interpreter, and author.

Comment: I end up getting this error   TestLibrary.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
  list.searchSong("hello","world","luar","me");
      ^
  symbol:   method searchSong(String,String,String,String)
  location: variable list of type Library

Comment: @luar:  I think that might be caused by that stray `}` there.  Might want to look into that.

Comment: @jahroy: No.  `list` is an instance of `Library`.  Provided that the call to `searchSong` **is in the same scope** as the variable he believes he's referencing, then that code should work *fine*.

Comment: Oops... you're right.  MY bad.

Answer (score 2):

it should be :

```
list.searchSong("hello","world","luar","me");
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared String values in parameters of your searchSong() method.

So, when you call the method in your main, it should be:

`list.searchSong("hello","world","luar","me");`